# Swift Write Video NSData to Gallery

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, xcode

I am writing an iOS application on swift that downloads a video from a URL and writes it to the disk. I am getting the data but have so far been unsuccessful in writing to disk. Below is the code:

```
let yourURL = NSURL(string: "http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_10mb.mp4")
    //Create a URL request
    let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: yourURL!)
    //get the data
    var theData = NSData();
    do{
        theData = try NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(urlRequest, returningResponse: nil)
    }
    catch let err as NSError
    {

    }

    try! PHPhotoLibrary.sharedPhotoLibrary().performChangesAndWait({ ()-> Void in
        if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
            PHAssetCreationRequest.creationRequestForAsset().addResourceWithType(PHAssetResourceType.Video, data: theData, options: nil)

            print("SUCESS");
        } else {

        };

    });
```

I am receiving the following error, any insight appreciated:

```
fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=-1 "(null)": file /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-703.0.18.1/src/swift/stdlib/public/core/ErrorType.swift, line 54
```

Comment: Rather than using `try!`, use `do`-`try`-`catch` pattern and print the resulting `error` object. It may give you a more meaningful error message.

Comment: I get a similar error when I try that: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=-1 "(null)"

Comment: I am new to iOS programming so I am still learning as I'm going. I'm sorry but what is localizedDescription and userInfo you are referring to? And yes, the app has requested and has access to the photos library.

Comment: When I printed the localizedDescription out, I got the following message: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error -1.)"

Comment: Yes the data is non nil when I set up a break point to check.

Answer (score 1):

One issue is that you are trying to load the video (which can be quite large) into memory in a `NSData`. It's much better if you can stream to and from files in persistent storage, instead. You can accomplish this by using `NSURLSession` download task rather than using the deprecated `NSURLConnection` method, `sendSynchronousRequest`.

By using `NSURLSession` download task, you avoid trying to hold a large video in memory at one time and it will, instead, stream the video directly to persistent storage. (Note, do not use `NSURLSession` data task, as that will have the same memory footprint problems as the deprecated method `sendSynchronousRequest` of `NSURLConnection`.)

Once the `NSURLSession` download task has streamed the download directly to the persistent storage, you can then move the file to the temporary file and then use `addResourceWithType`, again supplying a file URL rather than a `NSData`.

When I did that (and adding some other useful error checking), it seemed to work fine:

```
// make sure it's authorized

PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization { authorizationStatus in
    guard authorizationStatus == .Authorized else {
        print("cannot proceed without permission")
        return
    }

    self.downloadVideo()
}
```

Where:

```
func downloadVideo() {
    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

    // create request

    let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_10mb.mp4")!
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().downloadTaskWithURL(url) { location, response, error in
        // make sure there weren't any fundamental networking errors

        guard location != nil && error == nil else {
            print(error)
            return
        }

        // make sure there weren't and web server errors

        guard let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse where httpResponse.statusCode == 200 else {
            print(response)
            return
        }

        // move the file to temporary folder

        let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory())
            .URLByAppendingPathComponent(url.lastPathComponent!)

        do {
            try fileManager.moveItemAtURL(location!, toURL: fileURL)
        } catch {
            print(error)
            return
        }

        // now save it in our photo library

        PHPhotoLibrary.sharedPhotoLibrary().performChanges({
            PHAssetCreationRequest.creationRequestForAsset().addResourceWithType(.Video, fileURL: fileURL, options: nil)
        }, completionHandler: { success, error in
            defer {
                do {
                    try fileManager.removeItemAtURL(fileURL)
                } catch let removeError {
                    print(removeError)
                }
            }

            guard success && error == nil else {
                print(error)
                return
            }

            print("SUCCESS")
        })
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Note, because `NSURLSession` is more stringent about making sure you don't perform insecure requests, you may want to update the `info.plist` (right click on it and choose "Open As" - "Source Code") and add this to the file:

```xml
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>sample-videos.com</key>
        <dict>
            <!--Include to allow subdomains-->
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <!--Include to allow HTTP requests-->
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <!--Include to specify minimum TLS version-->
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.1</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

But, when I did all of that, the video was downloaded and added to my photos library successfully. And note that I excised all synchronous requests here (`NSURLSession` is asynchronous, as is `performChanges`), as you almost never want to perform synchronous requests (and certainly never on the main queue).